# DOMPDF Leaving Blank Page After page-break-inside:avoid

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I am creating a PDF document in that some of content which I want to keep in the same page.

I used the css style like:

```
.page-break-inside-avoid{ display: block; page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

I also tried this style:

```
.page-break-inside-avoid{ page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

The content remains in the same page but one more issue I realized, it is leaving a blank page after the content which I want to put in the same page.

Please can anyone have solution regarding this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?